# Get Drill down URL from FusionCharts events

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm working with FusionCharts (specifically a column chart). The chart is created from a rest endpoint that outputs chart xml. The endpoint also encodes xml-urls into the chart for drill-down. I want to capture these urls in order to change the contents of the surrounding form (to make it appear the parameters chosen generated that chart).

The problem I'm running into is that the `BeforeLinkedItemOpen` and `LinkedItemOpened` events do not contain the url the chart is pulling its xml from. 
The `LinkedChartInvoked` event does contain this information - its just only called navigating the first level of the drill-down.

I have five levels of drill-down, so that won't work. Anyone know of a way to get the information I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find an answer for this. It appears that FusionCharts simply does not report this information and I could not do what I was trying to do.